# Changing Backgrounds Not Working as Expected

Tags: fabricjs

I'm currently using the following to set an image and replace it as needed (with fabricjs 1.7.22), but I'm trying to get away from `onclick=` so am opting to replace the background with a number of `id`s with jQuery.

**Currently, things look something like this:**

*My HTML*

```
<a onclick="replaceImage(oImg, '../images/1.png')" class="dropdown-item">Image Name 1</a>
<a onclick="replaceImage(oImg, '../images/2.png')" class="dropdown-item">Image Name 2</a>
```

*My JS*

```
// Image Replacing
function replaceImage(oImgObj, imgUrl) {
  if (!isImageLoaded) return; //return if initial image not loaded
  var imgElem = oImgObj._element; //reference to actual image element
  imgElem.src = imgUrl; //set image source
  imgElem.onload = () => canvas1.renderAll(); //render on image load
}

// Default Image
fabric.Image.fromURL('../images/images/0.png'', function (img) {
  isImageLoaded = true;
  oImg = img.set({
    selectable: false,
    evented: false,
  }).scale(0.5);
  canvas1.add(oImg).renderAll();
  canvas1.sendToBack(oImg);
});
```

**What I'm trying now, but isn't working:**

*My HTML*

```
<a id="i0" class="dropdown-item">Image 1</a>
<a id="i1" class="dropdown-item">Image 2</a>
```

*My JS*

```
$("#i0").click(function () {
  canvas1.setBackgroundImage('../images/0.png', canvas1.renderAll.bind(canvas1), {
    // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
});

$("#i1").click(function () {
  canvas1.setBackgroundImage('../images/1.png', canvas1.renderAll.bind(canvas1), {
    // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top'
  });
});
```

When I click one of the latter buttons, nothing happens and I don't get any errors so this is throwing me for a loop. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this

```
    $(".page-content").css("background-image", "url('css/images/uimage.png')");
```

instead of

```
    canvas1.setBackgroundImage('../images/0.png', canvas1.renderAll.bind(canvas1), {
// Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
originX: 'left',
originY: 'top'
```

Comment: So I'm currently sending images to back with `sendToBack`, can you confirm whether this works with that?

Comment: No,it does not work with "sendToBack" but for this functionality you can use "z-index" css property to send images back.

Answer (score 1):

You are using jQuery instead of JavaScript in your code. So put all your jquery code in ready function like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //....jQuery code here
    });
```

Also, if your code still doen't work then use on click function like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#i0').on('click', function () {
            // ....your code here
        })
     });
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to change anything. I'll write up a JSFiddle shortly.